# Visual Studio 2010 and aspnet_sql.exe?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Would anyone know where aspnet_sql.exe went to in Visual Studio 2010? Or what I should be using instead? Google is turning up spurious noise.

Jeff

Comment: Isn't the command known as aspnet_regsql.exe? It should be in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the command known as `aspnet_regsql.exe`? It should be in *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe*

In Win7 there is a `WHERE` console command. So use that to find your EXE file.

Comment: Thanks Huske - I had no hope since I was looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio...